# Most simple example where series expanding a root object actually fails due to branchcuts

Tags: equation-solving, series-expansion

When computing the series expansion of a `Root` object, *Mathematica* throws an error like: "Because of branch cuts, the series may represent a different root of [root expression] for some values of [expansion parameter]". However, I always compare the results I get with the "exact" numerical result and it always, within a certain region, yields a good approximation.

Could somebody maybe show me a simple example of a `Root`-object, series expanded around a point x, where due to branch cuts, the result is actually not good. If I misunderstand this completely, please explain, what is meant by this warning, and what *Mathematica* is actually trying to warn me about.

Comment: Well, due to *Mathematica* assuming that all variables can take complex values unless told otherwise, *Mathematica* is just being cautious. It can happen that substituting an arbitrary complex number into your series expansion will yield a value very much different from one you might get from directly evaluating a `Root[]` object.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you post the `Root` object that produces the issue in your question. Then we'd be able to see if the message is justified or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what the "simplest" example would be, but here is one:

```
f[z_] := Root[z + 2 #1 + #^3 - #1^4 &, 1]

Plot3D[Im[f[x + I y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Re[z]", "Im[z]", "Im[f[z]]"}]
```

[image: landscape]

Here you see two regions near the origin that are bounded by discontinuities of the imaginary part (branch cuts). In these regions, a `Series` expansion will converge only within a radius that doesn't intersect the boundaries. To test this, do the expansion about points in both regions. Here, you **will get the warnings mentioned in the question** both times:

```
f1[z_] = Normal@Series[f[z], {z, .2 + I .004, 3}];

f2[z_] = Normal@Series[f[z], {z, .2 - I .004, 3}];
```

Now compare if all three functions are almost the same at a single point:

```
f[.2 - I .004]

(* ==> -0.309233 - 1.03775 I *)

f2[.2 - I .004]

(* ==> -0.309233 - 1.03775 I *)

f1[.2 - I .004]

(* ==> -0.3088 + 1.03621 I *)
```

The first result is the original function, and clearly only one of the `Series` expansions (`f2`) is valid at the point `z == .2 - I .004`. That's because it was centered in the region where that point lies.

The other expansion, `f1`, is off by a large amount even though it was done around a point `z == .2 + I .004` that is just on the opposite side of the branch cut along the real axis by a tiny amount.